# Remember "Open location" for next time?

Tags: nautilus

I'm accustomed to clicking on the desktop, then typing ^L to get the Open location window into which I then type ssh://some-domain. This works, I get to muck with my files there.

What I want is not to have to type this address in each time--particularly since the newly opened window times out so quickly and shuts down (making me perform this action all over again every 10 minutes or so).

I would like to know how this dialog might remember what I type from time to time OR how to make Nautilus (?) leave my window open until I'm done with and close it.

Thanks,

Russ Bateman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Connect to Server..." option in the Places menu (Gnome2) can connect over SSH. I know in it, there's an option to create a bookmark to the location. I don't know if it will solve your timeout issue (I always just use the terminal for SSH stuff), but it should save you the steps to open the window.

Comment: Uh, now I understand... I tried this a few times, but didn't feel it was worth naming the bookmark, thinking it would just use the server name. However, it was the thing that was leaving a mysterious "(null)" in my Places list. Thanks.

Comment: Haha. You would think it would use the server name, or yell at you for having that field blank.